# Calling flow from another project in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I like to call a flow from another project in Mule. Is that possible.

If its so please provide me the details how it can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are separate projects(even on the same JVM) then you cannot use `flow-ref` but will have to use a transport such as JMS, HTTP etc. If you are using Mule 3.5 Enterprise Edition then you can use the VM transport to communicate between projects using the new shared resources and domain functionality. More info on that here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Shared+Resources